# How do I get access to a user's calendar?

Tags: c#, calendar, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

How do I get access to a user's calendar via EWS?

Using **EWS 2.0, Exchange2010_SP1**

My program should connect to an Exchange server and synchronize all calendar appointments with a separate database. For this issue a "power user" was created. He can see all the shared calendars of target users. I use **`exchangeService.SyncFolderItems`** to synchronize appointmets of the default user, but how can I access to all other users calendar to synchronize appointments?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Exchange Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204095%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) to allow your power user to "act as" the other users. You'll set the exchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId property each time you need to impersonate a user.

With regards,

Comment: thanks. yes I already tried this, but if I try to bind a calendar folder after that, I get an error: ErrorImpersonateUserDenied.
Is there maybe another way?

Comment: Can you run Get-ManagementRoleAssignment and show us the results of that cmdlet? It seems like impersonation is not setup correctly. Also, while we're at it, provide us with the XML request and response so we can see what you are trying to do.